# how to sum multiple sql queries in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

how can i sum multiple queries and send them to blade file?
i have a query and retrieve the "preferencesProducts" from database, so according to them, i need to retrieve the products too. this is my controller code:

```
$preferences = DB::table('preferences')->where('customerId', $req->id)->get();
```

so according to "preference" of above query, i should retrieve another data to, so i make a foreach to extract the  $preferencesProducts and then write my query and saving it to a variable called $preferences

```
            foreach($preferences as $preference)
            {
                $preferencesedProducts= $preferencesedProducts.DB::table('products')->where('productsubCategory', $preference->preference)->get();
            }
```

as it going into a loop, it makes multiple queries, so how can i sum and send them to blade file?

my code:

```
return view('/customers/customerHome')->with('preferencesedProducts', $preferencesedProducts);
```

Comment: You should create a method in model with hasmany relation.(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) Then you can initilize it with eager loading.(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) on the result of preferences query to get an array of preferences and query the products with [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses):

```
$preferences = DB::table('preferences')->where('customerId', $req->id)->get();

$preferencesedProducts = DB::table('products')->whereIn('productsubCategory', $preferences->pluck('preference'))->get();
```

Comment: not working, for example: the preferences values are ( mobile, computer, T-shirt...) which these are subCategories in "products" table, i need to access the preferences values and according them, retrieve the categories from "products" table. this will result to retrieve only one preference